# Insert a list of user inputs into a list of lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to create  a student record system in haskell wherein I have to take a user input of name, birthday month and birthday date and then perform operations such as searching deleting etc. So i thought of creating lists of lists. each list has a list inside it that contains record of each person. But I am unable to code it.

code is as follows:

```
type data = [String,Int,Int]
insert :: (eq a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
  print "Enter the name"
  name <- getLine
  print "Enter the month"
  month <- getLine
  print "Enter the date"
  date <- getLine
  insert [] = [data]
    where 
      data = date:data
      data = month: data
      data = name : data
```

I don't know how to proceed after this. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with this code

1. `print`, `getLine` needs the `IO` monad.
2. `data` is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as a variable name.  You've also defined the value of `data` 3 times.
3. `insert` has a type, but no definition.
4. There is no `main`
5. I think you meant to use `Eq a=>`, not (eq a)....  But I am not sure.

Comment: You forgot : 6) print... are all at the top level, not in the definition of insert ; 7) insert is only defined for an empty list ; 8) Type names must start with an uppercase letter (linked with the data issue) ; 9) A list can't contain several different types, that's for tuples ;

Comment: I have declared the IO monad on the top. Just didn't include that. I rectified the use of data keyword. Yes I have to use Eq => a and also main is defined somewhere like in a switch case so control returns to that.

Comment: Can you show me or refer a sample code for this. How to do manipulations like these ? Thanks for the answers.